# Isc-dhcp-server not starting error: not configured to listen to any interfaces

Tags: configuration-files, dhcp

I have installed Isc-dhcp-server and configured the files accordingly still it is showing the error that its not configured to listen to any interfaces. 
i have ubuntu 17.04 64 bit

## Interface file :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 10.90.90.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.90.90.1
broadcast 10.90.90.255
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
up service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

## in /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server file

```
   INTERFACES="enp2s0"
```

## /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf file:

```
 subnet 10.90.90.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
      range 10.90.90.10 10.90.90.20;
      default-lease-time 600;
      max-lease-time 7200;
      option routers 10.90.90.1;
    }
```

## Error i'm getting :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCrol.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my isc-dhcp-server configuration file was getting reset to original file with blank interfaces.
I did re-installation of ubuntu and it worked all well.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but :

`isc-dhcp-server` as configuration file in `/etc/default` folder named `isc-dhcp-server` is this file at the very last line you must set the interface wich `isc-dhcp-server` will listen :

```
# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#       Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACESv4="eth0 eth1"
INTERFACESv6=""
```

Try with `INTERFACESv4` key.

Then restart the server.

```
server isc-dhcp-server restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like your interface `enp2s0` isn't up. You can check this by using `ifconfig`.

You can fix it by putting: `auto enp2s0` under `auto lo` in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: My interface is up.
I have checked it using ifconfig